# Do Kensai's and Inspired Blade's capstones stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus, gestalt

This will never occur in normal gameplay, but a situation has come up in a Level 20 Gestalt game I'm playing in that may also apply to Level 40 Epic games (should such a thing happen).

A player has created a character gestalting Kensai Magus and Inspired Blade Swashbuckler. The end result includes the following two capstones in question.

From [Kensai](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/kensai/):

> At 20th level, a kensai gains weapon mastery with his favored weapon, as the fighter class ability.

From [Fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Weapon-Mastery-Ex-) (for reference):

> At 20th level, a fighter chooses one weapon, such as the longsword, greataxe, or longbow. Any attacks made with that weapon automatically confirm all critical threats and have their damage multiplier increased by 1 (×2 becomes ×3, for example). In addition, he cannot be disarmed while wielding a weapon of this type.

And from [Inspired Blade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/archetypes/paizo-swashbuckler-archetypes/inspired-blade/):

> At 20th level, when an inspired blade threatens a critical hit with a rapier, that critical hit is automatically confirmed. Furthermore, the critical threat range increases by 1 (this increase to the critical threat range stacks with the increase from rapier training, to a total threat range of 14–20), and the critical modifier of the weapon increases by 1 (×2 becomes ×3, for example).

According to [the hybrid class page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes):

> Each one of the following classes lists two classes that it draws upon to form the basis of its theme. While a character can multiclass with these parent classes, this usually results in redundant abilities. Such abilities don’t stack unless specified.

Thus, the question has come up - because the character is wielding a rapier with a 14-20/x4 crit range that he's then spending around 10 Panache/turn to auto-threaten and other abilities allow him to auto-confirm - do these two abilities stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason why they wouldn’t. They do not use the same name or imply they are the same ability, and the only feature they have in common is the increase to critical damage multiplier—a rare benefit to be sure, but nothing says you cannot have more than one.

Comment: Actually, both abilities also auto-confirm threats, but no issues with that stacking.